# Interrupt function if condition is fulfilled C#

Tags: c#, wrapper, interrupt, converters

I think the question is not the smartest one, but i got stuck with this problem. I am writing a binary file to excel file converter. A binary file consists of several groups of information. Each group exists in different versions. In addition, the size of each group is indicated in bytes. Now the problem. I would like to cancel my read function when the size in bytes is reached. Unfortunately I do not know how to do this. Do you have a tip for me?

```
 public override void ReadData()
    {
        DaConvOffs1 = TypConversions.Number(Reader.ReadInt32());
        DaConvOffs2 = TypConversions.Number(Reader.ReadInt32());
        DaConvGain1 = TypConversions.Number(Reader.ReadInt32());
        DaConvGain2 = TypConversions.Number(Reader.ReadInt32());
        AdConvCalib1 = TypConversions.Number(Reader.ReadInt32());
        AdConvCalib2 = TypConversions.Number(Reader.ReadInt32());
        DbPerVolt = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());  //Math.Abs
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            AntiCCor[i] = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        }
        CalibLevel = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        MicroSens = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        CurSens = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        CurCalDate = TypConversions.Time(Reader.ReadInt32());
        CurCalLevel = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        MicrSpecSens = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        MicrSpecCalibDate = TypConversions.Time(Reader.ReadInt32());
        MicrCalibLevel = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        Zf0023Used = TypConversions.EnumDecoder(Reader.ReadInt16(), 26);
        MicrUnspecSens = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        MicrUnspecCalibDate = TypConversions.Time(Reader.ReadInt32());
        AcSens = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        AcCalibDate = TypConversions.Time(Reader.ReadInt32());
        AcCalibLevel = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        MicrUnspecRefCiCDate = TypConversions.Time(Reader.ReadInt32());
        MicrUnspecRefCicRatio = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        MicrUnspecRefCicSnRatio = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        MicrRefCicDate = TypConversions.Time(Reader.ReadInt32());
        MicrRefCicRatio = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        MicroRefCicSnRatio = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        CurRefCicDate = TypConversions.Time(Reader.ReadInt32());
        CurRefCicRatio = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
        CurRefCicSnRatio = TypConversions.Db100(Reader.ReadInt16());
```

If the bytes have now added up to 200 bits via Reader.ReadInt32..., then you should abort. Can I solve this somehow, for example with an interrupt?

Comment: Hello Lars, could you please confirm? Some binary file has DaConvOffs1 ,DaConvOffs2 etc. and some hasn't. And when readed data arrived to 200 bit you need to exit from reading. Is it true?

Comment: ja das lesen muss abgebrochen werden, wenn eine bestimme anzahl an Bytes eingelesen worden ist. Dabei wird einfach in der funktion von oben nach unten eingelesen. Zum beispiel: (Gruppengröße: 64 Bit) 
 
DaConvOffs1 = TypConversions.Number(Reader.ReadInt32());
DaConvOffs2 = TypConversions.Number(Reader.ReadInt32());
Function Exit

Comment: I used translator to understand you. But in c# you can use "return" for Function Exit equivalent call. Do you asking that ?

Comment: I know that a “return” exit a function at the point where you use it. The problem is, that I need a a little bit dynamic. So if I want to read 150 Bit I need to exit the method after 150 Bit reading. I need the possibility to exit after every read. 
Btw sorry for using German instead of English.

Comment: Sorry for late, if you need a dynamic way, you can add a parameter to function. Do you asking that?

like 

`public override void ReadData(int requiredBitsForExit)`